# Making sure that only one request is processed at a time and other requests incoming are discarded

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have a goroutine, let's call it `goProcessor`, which processes requests coming in from other goroutines.

`goProcessor` can only process one request at a time. If a requests, let's call it **req2**, comes in while `goProcessor` is still processing the previous **req1** request, **req2** has to be discarded and will be simply lost.

I have implemented such logic using an unbuffered channel and the `select` statement, but I am not sure whether there could be a simpler more elegant way to accomplish what I want. A simple example of my solution is this

```
var c = make(chan string)

func main() {

    goRequest := func(request string, delay int) {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(delay) * time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Here I am request %v\n", request)
        select {
        case c <- request:
            fmt.Printf("%v sent\n", request)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%v discarded\n", request)
        }
    }

    goProcessor := func() {
        for {
            msg := <-c
            fmt.Println("received", msg)
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("processed", msg)
        }
    }

    go goRequest("First req", 1)
    go goRequest("Second req", 2)
    go goRequest("Third req", 5)
    go goProcessor()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Main has finished")
}
```

Comment: @icza thanks. I was imagining a solution using some sort of mutex that answers with some error when somebody tries to lock it when already locked. But could not find anything, so I reverted to channels.

Comment: Converting my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is perfectly fine and clean. Only thing you could simplify on it is to use `for range` in `goProcessor()` like this:

```
for msg := range c {
    // ...
}
```

but other than that it's idiomatic.

A "TryLock" might come to mind to use here. There is no "TryLock" in the standard lib (there are [3rd party libs](https://github.com/LK4D4/trylock) for that), but using it isn't simpler or more idiomatic in your case, you have to check if `TryLock()` returns `true`, and you have to unlock it. And you still need a channel to send the results to the processor, so your solution is simpler and cleaner.